# How can I add condition in select ? (Vue.JS 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have vue component like this :

```
<script>
    export default{
        template: '\
            <select class="form-control" v-on:change="search">\
                <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id ? option.id+\'|\'+option.name : \'\'">{{ option.name }}</option>\
            </select>',
        mounted() {
            this.fetchList();
        },
        ...
    };
</script>
```

It works. No error

But, I want to add condition again in select

If it meets the conditions then `selected`

I add condition like this :

```
template: '\
            <select class="form-control" v-on:change="search">\
                <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id ? option.id+\'|\'+option.name : \'\'" option.id == 1 ? \'selected\' : \'\'>{{ option.name }}</option>\
            </select>',
```

There exist error like this :

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "option" is not defined on the instance
>   but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data
>   properties in the data option.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work. Change your code like this.

```
<option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id ? option.id+\'|\'+option.name : \'\'" v-bind:selected="option.id == 1">{{ option.name }}</option>\
```

Since `selected` is boolean attribute you'll have to use `v-bind:selected="<condition>"`. This will insert the attribute based on the conditional's result.

Answer (score 4):

I would change to a **[`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events)** based:

```
<select @change="search" v-model="select">
  <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.id">
    {{ option.name }}
  </option>
</select>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: [Number, String]
  },
  data() {
    return { select: this.value };
  },
  watch: {
    value: function (val) {
      this.select = val;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // ...
  }
};
</script>
```